# How to log duplicate rows removed using Sort function in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to log the rows to a flat file that were removed using the sort functions in SSIS?

Comment: What kind of data source are you using?

Comment: I am using MS SQL table.

Comment: KeithL hit on what I was getting at with my question about your source. You could use row_number() or some similar method to identify duplicates in your source query. Then use a conditional split to route rowNumber = 1 to destination and rowNumber > 1 to a flat file, which would contain your duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use aggregate instead of sort. Add all columns into the aggregate and use an aggregation of count.

Run through a multicast and have one flow go normally and the 2nd flow can go through a conditional split splitting out where counts are >1. This will give you the duplicates to handle.

EDIT:

The default aggregation operation is group by. The easiest way to implement this is to check the box next to name in the editor which will select all (group by) and also add in a count of each group.

EDIT2:

You said you have a SQL Source, consider using

```
row_Number() over (partition by [primary key] order by [EnteredDate] desc)
```

This column will give you something to key off of for splitting.

Actually, it would have to be foreign key to have duplication in the table.

Comment: I read about that. I wasn't sure when doing a "group by" if it would look to see if all the columns were unique or. I just want to compare one column.

Comment: you would group by everything

Comment: So in my case, grouping by PrimaryKey+Description would mean that even if the PrimaryKey is duplicate, it won't be grouped if the description is not the same. Right?

Comment: correct. the description would have to match 100% to be considered duplicate

Comment: Is there a way to just check PrimaryKey?

Comment: you said you have a sql source, why not handle all of this in your extract syntax?

Comment: Anyway, yes but you will lose data if you excluded description in your aggregation.